# How can I make PHPStorm auto-import namespaces in use statements?

Tags: phpstorm

I have checked the box for "Enable auto-import in namespace scope" in preferences, however when I select a class from the autocomplete, the FQN remains rather than placing it in a use statement. What am I doing wrong and how can I force phpstorm to auto-import these?

Comment: Is the file where you are doing this is namespaced as well? It works fine for me. Please also try with 1) all 3rd-party plugins disabled 2) after "File | Invalidate Caches..." and restart (who knows...) Also -- any chance for some screencast (to see what exactly is going on, in case you somehow do it differently)?

Comment: Embarrassingly enough, the file was improperly namespaced. If you would like to submit this comment as an answer, I will select it as the answer.

Comment: I just discovered it didn't work for me, because I had enabled Power Save Mode. So, check if you have it enabled (menu File -> Power Save Mode) and see if disabling it makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of today (PhpStorm 2022.1), you should select `prefer import` option in `Editor > General > Autoimport` instead of `prefer FQN`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.
So strange that searching "auto import" in settings does not show that area of configuration settings :-(
Also found this in the official IntelliJ IDEA help site https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#import-packages-instead-of-single-classes

Answer (score 25):

Make sure that the file where you performing this is actually properly namespaced (as that is the requirement for `Enable auto-import in namespace scope` option).

If working in non-namepsaced file .. you should enable `Enable auto-import in file scope` option (it is not enabled by default for better compatibility with older existing code reasons).

Comment: Here the documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/auto-import.html

Comment: Also `Enable auto-import from the global scope` seemingly forces to use  `use` statements instead of putting a prepending a backslash.

Comment: @UmurKaragöz That is correct .. as that's what "import" means. In **2018.1** they have introduced a better control .. and you now can use prepending slash instead .. or rely on fallback logic. But that's general (covers file and namespace scope at the same time)